# any good books on scalable web applications (Java/Ajax/REST)?

Tags: java, ajax, rest, scalability

Are there any good books on the subject worth reading and still up-to-date with current technologies?

I'm mostly interested in back-end architecture and things I should consider choosing clustering and database solution as I plan to use GWT for the front-end therefore won't be able to control a lot there.

I'm looking for a book which will answer questions like: How to choose load balancing strategy? What DB model to choose? How to scale data? How to scale request handling? What are common problems when building web application able to handle huge traffic?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907260/how-to-design-scalable-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About GWT: [Google Web Toolkit Applications](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321501969).

In general [Even faster web sites performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304) and [Building scalable web sites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102357) are very nice.

I have heard good words on [The Art of Capicity Planning](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518585) too, but i don't have it, so i cannot say from first-hand experience.

Answer (score 2):

Check out O'Reilly's books.  Here's one on [High Performance Web Sites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529307).

Comment: thanks. added to my wish list at Amazon but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for. Seems like good book but from description it looks like the author talks a lot about where to put script etc while if I plan to use GWT I won't be able to control it. Probably should update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about books, but if you want information regarding real world, up to the bleeding edge, scalable web applications and architecture, then [highscalability](http://highscalability.com/) is a must read.

Answer (score 1):

[Perfomance Analysis for Java Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201844540) by Stacey Joines et al?

My take is that Ajax doesn't fundamentally affect the overall approach to scalability. It may place even greater emphasis on the intelligent use of caching, but overall everything we knew about scalabilty remains true.

Comment: Publisher: Addison Wesley (19 Sep 2002)
isn't it a bit outdated? A lot of things happened since 2002, new challenges, new solutions, new technologies... but I agree that probably basics are the same.