# Papers on 'sharding designs' in large live, concurrent multi-user multi-machine systems

Tags: concurrency

Can anyone provide the current definitive papers on 'sharding designs' currently used in large, live, concurrent multi-user multi-machine systems.

I mean where there is a large amount of live shared state - between interacting actors, and this shared state splits in half into two groups of actors.

JG

---

EDIT

The usage scenario I'm talking about is where you have > 1000 users across > 10 machines. The question is how do you make your shared state scale, but split at an appropriate time. Scenarios might be online chat window with > 10000 users, Google Shared spaces applets, or an MMO.

Comment: Are you talking about things like Design Patterns?  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern )

Comment: I've read GOF. The usage scenario I'm talking about is where you have > 1000 users across > 10 machines. The question is how do you make your shared state scale, but split at an appropriate time. Scenarios might be online chat window with > 10000 users, Google Shared spaces applets, or an MMO.

Comment: I didn't say 'read GOF'. I was wondering what exactly are you looking for, and whether you are hoping to find something along the lines of a pattern.

Comment: Fair enough. In honesty I was going to spread the net as far wide as possible. If patterns are available - I'll take that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some related ideas:

- [Design](http://www.slideshare.net/tinniamvganesh/design-principles-of-scalable-distributed-systems)
- [Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907343/15441)
- [Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform#Search_infrastructure)
- [Index design](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building)
- [Index querying](http://code.google.com/p/shard-query/)